# Why does Laravel replace a tab by a "=09" string when sending mails?

Tags: php, email, laravel

I'm using the following code to send mails in Laravel:

```
\Mail::send('emails.mailing', $data,
    function ($message) use ($user) {
        $message
          ->to($user->email, $user->first_name)
          ->subject('some nice subject');
});
```

The emails/mailing.blade.php file contains the html with a lot of tabs to make the syntax nicer for coding, however when I look at the source of the recieved email, all tabs are replaced by a "=09" string.

What is causing this, and how can I fix this?

edit: One i.m.o. good solution would be to remove all tabs before sending the mail. How would I do this?

Comment: [Quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)

Answer (score 4):

=09 is the `quoted-printable` encoding for a tab character (see [RFC 1521](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521.html).) [On his blog](https://zachalam.com/send-correctly-formatted-html-emails-with-laravel-and-swiftmailer/), Zach Alam suggests telling it to use the 8-bit encoder instead of the default (QP) one:

```
$message->setEncoder(Swift_Encoding::get8BitEncoding());
```

In the context of your code, this could likely be done via:

```
\Mail::send('emails.mailing', $data,
    function ($message) use ($user) {
        $message
          ->setEncoder(Swift_Encoding::get8BitEncoding())
          ->to($user->email, $user->first_name)
          ->subject('some nice subject');
});
```

Comment: Hmm I'm getting an error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Swift_Encoding' not found in /var/www/site.com/releases/20141023075449/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/SerializableClosure.php(99) : eval()'d code on line 2. Apparently I don't have (and use) Swift Mailer.

Comment: You'll need to install that class, and either include it, or make sure your auto-includer can find it.

Comment: I can't manage to get this working. I've got a swiftmailer map in the vendor map, so I guess that should include the right functions. How can I autoload this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

For the question of your edit, you can remove all tabs from the message before sending it with this :

```
$message_in_your_emails_mailing_view = str_replace(chr(9), '', $message_in_your_emails_mailing_view);
```

Comment: $message is not a string but a Illuminate\Mail\Message. Therefore this does not work :(

Comment: My bad, sorry. I've edited my answer, the message (and the code) you have to modify is in your emails.mailing view.