# Laravel 9: Malformed characters for emails in laravel.log

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, php-8

If I adjust in my Laravel 9 project (PHP 8), the `.env` - file to `MAIL_MAILER=log`.
The mail is saved in the `laravel.log` file, but the problem is, that some characters are malformed. For example the mail-`<head>` looks like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset=3D"utf-8">
    <meta name=3D="viewport" content=3D"width=3Ddevice-width, initial-scale=3D1.0">
    <meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3DUTF-8">
    <meta name=3D"color-scheme" content=3D"light">
    <meta name=3D"supported-color-schemes" content=3D"light">
</head>
```

The malformed characters also occur for äöü and other UTF-8 characters (e.g. `ä` resolves to `=C3=A4`).
If I'm using `MAIL_MAILER=smtp` the mail isn't malformed at all.
This makes local email debugging hard.

Anyway, this probably causes another problem on production. I'm using the package (https://github.com/shvetsgroup/laravel-email-database-log) to save all sent mails of Laravel in the database. Here the malformed characters are also saved in the database.

I'm sending mails like this:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::to('mail@mail.de')->queue(new \App\Mail\ContactConfirmation(
    $name,
    $message
));

class ContactConfirmation extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(
        public string $name,
        public string $text
    )
    {
        //
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('mails.contact_confirmation')
            ->subject('Your message')
            ->with([
                'name' => $this->name,
                'text' => $this->text
            ]);
    }
}
```

This problem looks similar to https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32954, but the mails sent by SMTP have no problem and Laravel 9 uses the Symfony Mailer. There is also a similar question ([Why does Laravel replace a tab by a "=09" string when sending mails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525360/why-does-laravel-replace-a-tab-by-a-09-string-when-sending-mails)) from **2014**, but here is SwiftMailer used.

Is there some way to fix the malformed characters on production and local? And if not, are there alternatives to save the mail without the package and malformed characters into the database?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I am hitting the same issue

Comment: @Lee Sadly enough, no. :D

Comment: if it helps, as temporary solution I have been using is to wrap the returned email body string with quoted_printable_decode() before saving to the database.

Answer (score -2):

A work around to this it could be to create a new channel for logging. On laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/logging#creating-custom-channels-via-factories it is explained it how to do it.
The idea is that when a log for mailer is used for sending emails, if the message is quoted-printable, then it will be decoded it back to '8bit' string.
To achieve this a new Logger is created that extends from Illuminate\Log\Logger and override the debug method with the code that convert to '8bit'string.

First, create a class that extends from Illuminate\Log\Logger. For example App\Mail\Logging\CustomLogger.php  This contains the override to debug method.

```
namespace App\Mail\Logging;
use Illuminate\Log\Logger;
class CustomLogger extends Logger
{
    public function debug($message, array $context = []): void
    {
        $message = str_contains($message, "=3D") ? quoted_printable_decode($message) : $message;
        $this->writeLog(__FUNCTION__, $message, $context);
    }
}
```

Then create the logger class that will resolve the customLogger previously. Example app\Logging\CreateCustomMailLogger.php

```
namespace App\Logging;
use App\Mail\Logging\CustomLogger;
class CreateCustomMailLogger
{
    public function __invoke(array $config)
    {
         /**  @var \Illuminate\Log\Logger $log **/
        $log = resolve('log');
        return new CustomLogger($log->getLogger(), $log->getEventDispatcher());
    }
}
```

In config\logging.php file add a new channel using the CreateCustomMailLogger created before.

```
'maillog' => [
     'driver' => 'custom',
     'via' => \App\Logging\CreateCustomMailLogger::class
   ],
```

In the .env file set MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL to maillog, the channel in logging.php created before

```
MAIL_MAILER=log
MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL=maillog
```

This way when you set mailer to log, then this channel will be used and it will be logged as '8bit' string and not quoted-printable.

For futher details, check this reply from the same issue.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32954#issuecomment-1335488478

Hope this help!